# Print a 'X' pattern of '*'

Tags: python

I'm trying to print this pattern in Python:

```
*     *
 *   * 
  * *
   *
  * *
 *   *
*     *
```

And came up with this code:

```
size = 7
inner_size = size - 3
space=0

for i in range(inner_size):
    print (' ' * space + '*' + ' ' * inner_size + '*')
    inner_size -=2
    space +=1
print "    *"

t_size=7
t_inner_size = 0
space=3
for i in range(inner_size):
    print (' ' * space + '*' + ' ' * inner_size + '*')
    inner_size +=2
    space -=1
```

But, it prints this :

```
*    *
 *  *
  **
   **
    *
```

How to print the required pattern?
Is it possible to do this in one loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used ideas from your existing code in the question and made a few tweaks to do it in a single loop with simple, crystal clear code:

```
def xprint(size):
    i,j = 0,size - 1

    while j >= 0 and i < size:

        initial_spaces = ' '*min(i,j)
        middle_spaces = ' '*(abs(i - j) - 1)
        final_spaces = ' '*(size - 1 - max(i,j))

        if j == i:
            print initial_spaces + '*' + final_spaces
        else:
            print initial_spaces + '*' + middle_spaces + '*' + final_spaces

        i += 1
        j -= 1

xprint(7)
```

It prints out:

```
*     *
 *   * 
  * *  
   *   
  * *  
 *   * 
*     *
```

A linear-time straightforward way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:

```
def pattern(size):
    for i in range(size):
        print("".join("*" if j == i or size - 1 - j == i else " "
                      for j in range(size)))
```

Details:  `i` is the row index and `j` is the column index (both zero-based).  The `j == i` condition generates a diagonal from upper-left to lower-right.  The `size - 1 - j == i` condition generates a diagonal from upper-right to lower-left.  Together, they produce the X shape.

When called with a size of 7:

```
pattern(7)
```

It prints:

```
*     *
 *   * 
  * *  
   *   
  * *  
 *   * 
*     *
```

Note that it works with both even and odd sizes.  In the case of an even size, the resulting X will contain a 2x2 block of stars in the center.

Answer (score 3):

Just another way of solving the problem:

```
for i in range(5):
      for j in range(5):
           if ((i==j) or j==(5-i-1)):
               print " *",
           else:
               print " ",
       print ""
```

~

Answer (score 2):

You asked if it can be done with a '***single loop*'**. So there ya go:

```
n = 3
for i in range(-n, n + 1):
    print('{}*{}{}'.format(
        (n + 1 - abs(i)) * ' ',
        (2 * abs(i) - 1) * ' ',
        '' if i == 0 else '*'))
```

Explanation:

For any given line, we need 2 sets of spaces. Spaces before the first `*`, and spaces after the first `*`. This we are formatting our string as follows: `{}*{}`

Now we add an extra placeholder, because every line has 2x '*', except for the middle line. We're counting in a fashion similar to `-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3`, there middle line has index `0`. Thus now our string format has become `{}*{}{}`.

Now, space before the first `*` need `n + 1 - abs(i)` no. of spaces.
and spaces after the first `*` need `n + 1 - abs(i)` no of spaces.

Output (n=3):

```
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
```

Output (n=5):

```
 *         *
  *       *
   *     *
    *   *
     * *
      *
     * *
    *   *
   *     *
  *       *
 *         *
```

Although people are using the entire pattern size as input, I think it's more intuitive to use the recurring size as input. So just change the value of `n` as desired.

*PS: This is not the most elegant, nor is it the most legible solution. But it works in a* **single** *loop.*

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
pattern_size = 7
for t in range(pattern_size):
    pattern = list(" " * pattern_size)
    pattern[t] = "*"
    pattern[-(t+1)] = "*"
    print("".join(pattern))
```

Output:

```
*     *
 *   * 
  * *  
   *   
  * *  
 *   * 
*     *
```

Answer (score 0):

Another code for the above pattern

```
i = 0
j = 6
for row in range(7):
    for column in range(7):
        if(column == i or column == j):
            print("*",end="")
        else:
            print(" ",end="")
    print("\n")
    i += 1
    j -= 1
```

Results in:

```
*     *

 *   * 

  * *  

   *   

  * *  

 *   * 

*     *
```